# Unable to pass data to a component via props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to render a carousel. I could not pass state data **SliderArr** to make it render in **Slider.tsx**

How Can I pass data from one component to another?
Please kindly advise :)

Main.tsx

```
//some codes above
public render(): React.ReactElement<IAProps> {
         return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Slider>
                {this.state.data.map(item=>
                <div>
                  <Data 
                  key={item.id}
                  id={item.id}
                  title={item.title}
                  />   
               </div>
                )}
              </Slider>  
   </div>  

    );
  }
```

Slider.tsx

```
import *  as React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import './slider.scss';
import Data from './Data';
import { IconButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
function Slider(props){

   var SliderArr=[];
   SliderArr.push(Data);
   debugger;
   console.log(SliderArr);
//codes continues....
```

Data.tsx

```
import *  as React from 'react';

function Data(props){
        return(
            <div>
            <h1>{props.id}</h1>
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
            </div>

        )

}

export default Data;
```

---

2020-02-26 1604
I found a solution modifying the Slider.tsx

```
function Slider(props){

   var SliderArr=[];
   let temp=props.data;

   temp.map((i,index)=>
   {SliderArr.push(
   <Data id={i.id} 
   title={i.title}
   photo={i.photo}
   summary={i.summary}  
   />);
    }
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code as below

**Main.tsx**

```
<Slider data={this.state.data}>

</Slider>
```

**Slider.tsx**

```
function Slider(props){

    // You will get data as below
    props.data;
    // Code continues
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use "this" in functional components; props.data is enough;